Stability of analytic continuation
Let $(Q,\| \cdot \|)$ be a certain Banach space of entire functions, say certain functions of finite order that satisfy a growth condition of the form $|f(z)| \leq c e^{a|z|^\gamma}$ for some $c,a,\gamma > 0$. Let $K \subset \mathbb C$ be a compact set. Clearly, each $f \in Q$ can be extended uniquely from its values on $\mathbb C \setminus K$ to whole $\mathbb C$. Are there results that quantify this statement, in the sense that the analytic continuation can be done in a stable way, e.g., in the sense that an inequality of the form
$$
\| f-g \| \leq C \| R(f)-R(g) \|
$$
holds where $R$ denotes the operator
$$
Rf(z) = f(z), \ z \in \mathbb C \setminus K, \quad Rf(z)=0, \ z \in K.
$$

You can take a circle around $K$ and apply the maximum principle, for example. Details will depend on the exact Banach space you consider.
